# ssh tunnel via specific interface

Tags: linux, ssh, pptp, ssh-tunnel

```
Client -ssh-> Server --> Internet
```

Normally I initiate an ssh tunnel with: `ssh -D 1337 admin@nas`

On the server I have two interfaces: eth1 and ppp0. Right now it uses eth1 when tunneling, but I'd like to use ppp0 instead.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `-b`. But this is pointless unless ppp0 already has a route to `nas`.